# Flask/html - submit only one button on Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have folowing form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="button">
    <input type="text" name="search_input" id="search_input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" id="searchBtn" class="button">
</form>
```

Desired behavior is that when I enter some text to input field and hit Enter key, form shall post *submit/Search* and *search_input*.

Instead I get two separate posts:

```
request.form['submit'] =
ImmutableMultiDict([('submit', 'Save'), ('search_input', 'exampletext')])
ImmutableMultiDict([('search_input', 'exampletext'), ('submit', 'Search')])
```

I also tried to use following js, but the result is same:

```
var input = document.getElementById("search");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("searchBtn").click();
  }
});
```

Do you have any idea, what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your js script i understand that you want the form to only click search and not save when you press the enter key?

If that is so then you need to change the name of the two buttons because form submit uses the name attribute to identify elements.

Since both your inputs have the same name you get two posts.

Edit: I just found out that the first submit in the form is clicked by default when you press the enter key (Without needing any js code), So in your case when you press the enter key the first button (Save) is pressed by default and from your js script the second button (Search) is pressed.

So you just have to put the search button on top of the save button and use CSS to change the order in the webpage

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I changed names of both buttons, but the behavior is same as before. On Enter key hit I get: `[('submitBtn', 'Save'), ('search', 'example1')]` and `[('search', 'example1'), ('searchBtn', 'Search')]`